# how to commit file without keeping modification history on svn

Tags: svn

on SVN repository, we have a file which needs to be uploaded with an executable. However we do not want to keep the changes made on this file, so we'd like svn to just crush the old file without comparing it with the new one.

Is there another way to do it than to just delete file and save it again on svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way to do it than to just delete file and save it again on svn?

This is also doesn't helps. Subversion will keep all deleted versions forever.

So, basically answer is - No. You can't manage files in such way.

Well, actually onw way present - using svnadmin + svndumpfilter. But I can't recomend this way, because it require deep knowledge what are you doing. And if you ask such questions, you don't have this knowledge.